# How can I filter an ID by subscribing to an Observable

Tags: angular, observable, subscription

Below I am subscribing to an observable but just updating values for the first object. I am passing through ID = 413 I would like to filter the ID so I can only get that object, can anyone help me please?

Thanks

```
this.Ordersummary.subscribe(
        r => {
            if (r.length != 0) {
                this.thepackage = r[0];
                this.emptySummary = true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['packages/gbr/public']);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is ID here?

Comment: `this.packageid = parseInt((this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use map and filter. Or if you want the subscribe to only trigger for a specific value, then you have to filter first.

Something like this:

```
pipe(
  filter(item => item.ID === 413)
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Thanks but now I get property 'id' does not exist on type 'Ordersummary[]'

    `this.Ordersummary.pipe(
            filter(item => item.id === this.packageid)
        ).subscribe(
            r => {
                if (r.length != 0) {
                    console.log('R: ', r[0]);
                    this.thepackage = r[0];
                    this.emptySummary = true;
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['packages/gbr/public']);
                }
            });`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter only the necassary id then you may create a simple method like this,

```
filterById(yourId: number) {
    this.filteredPackage = this.thepackage.filter(package => package.id === yourId);
}
```

**Explanation:**

After assigning your response to the `this.thepackage` object inside subscribe(), your response is globally accessible via `this.thepackage` object. In order to get the single record who’s ID is 413, just pass the ID into the method `filterById()`. Since it’s bad to modify the original object, we assign the newly filtered item to a new variable `this.filteredPackage`.

```
this.filterById(yourId);    // yourId is 413 here
```

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand how I'd use this

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Ordersummary.pipe(
        filter((item: any) => item.id === this.packageid)
    ).subscribe(val => console.log('VAL: ', val));
```

I am not getting anything in console when I click on item 413